# go get failed: x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided

Tags: go

> go get code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket

I'm trying to install websocket using `go get`

However, given the `x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided` error.

I was google it: `cross-compilation requires disabling CGO`, so i `export CGO_ENABLED=0`,

but it always error

system: os x 10.9.1

go version: go1.2 darwin/amd64

go env:

> GOARCH="amd64"
>
> GOBIN=""
>
> GOCHAR="6"
>
> GOEXE=""
>
> GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
>
> GOHOSTOS="darwin"
>
> GOOS="darwin"
>
> GOPATH="/Users/xxx/gocode"
>
> GORACE=""
>
> GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec"
>
> GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
>
> TERM="dumb"
>
> CC="clang"
>
> GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -fno-caret-diagnostics
>   -Qunused-arguments -fno-common"
>
> CXX="clang++"
>
> CGO_ENABLED="0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install with homebrew? Try this:

`brew install go --cross-compile-common --with-cgo --use-gcc`

(source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/gyL_jeOyxQA)

Otherwise, just install the pre-built package.