# cannot use https in darwin-amd64 binary built on a linux-amd64

Tags: linux, go, cross-compiling, darwin

I build a darwin-amd64 version of my program on linux-amd64, the cross-compiling command is:

`GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 GOBIN=/tmp go install <myprogram>`

Before that I've prepared the darwin-amd64 tool-chain using:

`sudo GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 ./make.bash`

However, after giving this darwin-amd64 version binary to my colleagues, they can't use it for login  because login will send a HTTPS request, which will use CGO. Errmsg returned is:

`x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided`

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a certificate issue, as the one mentioned in "[Building Docker Images for Static Go Binaries](https://medium.com/@kelseyhightower/optimizing-docker-images-for-static-binaries-b5696e26eb07)"

> The reason for this is that on Linux systems the tls package reads the root CA certificates from `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`, which is missing from the scratch image.
> The Contributors app gets around this problem by bundling a copy of the root CA certificates and configuring outbound calls to use them.

So you can check if that `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` is there on your colleague's workstation.

But [this bug report suggests](https://github.com/laher/goxc/issues/10):

> Just got [some clarifications from go-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/golang-nuts/x509%2420failed%2420to%2420load%2420system%2420roots%2420and%2420no%2420roots%2420provided%7Csort:relevance/golang-nuts/tIK1ON3Pq6s/kCTpDht9vLUJ). It's due to cross-compile won't work for loading x509 cert...
>
> the cross-compiler can't use 'cgo' during compilation, but 'cgo' is required to access the root certificate store on Darwin.
>
> I had a similar issue, was solved after copying `crt` file from any of these linux distro. for golang to read the file, you have to place the file in the exact same directory.
> `crypto/x509` will loop over [all the possible certificate files](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8349).

Another solution involves cross-compiling with "[`export CGO_ENABLED=0`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21819696/6309)".

The [bug 8349](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8349) shows some progress too with more recent Go.

Comment: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker-cli/pull/13#issuecomment-48804118 is also interesting, using Go 1.3+